# scipy misc.derivative result is incorrect

Tags: python, scipy

I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong here...

I am experimenting with a simple and contrived function, taking it's derivative for certain values of x:

`f(x) = x^3`, then evaluating the derivative `f'(x) = 3x^2` for values of x at 1, 2, 3

```
>>> from scipy import misc
>>> def x2(x): return x*x*x
...
>>> misc.derivative(x2,1)
4.0
>>> misc.derivative(x2,2)
13.0
>>> misc.derivative(x2,3)
28.0
```

problem: the results are incorrect, they are all +1 greater than they should be (they should be 3, 12 and 27 respectively).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`scipy.misc.derivative` is not exact. It uses a central difference formula to compute the derivative. The default spacing is `1.0`, which is pretty high for a lot of applications. Reducing it gives more accurate results:

```
>>> from scipy import misc
>>> def x3(x): return x*x*x
... 
>>> misc.derivative(x3, 1)
4.0
>>> misc.derivative(x3, 1, dx=0.5)
3.25
>>> misc.derivative(x3, 1, dx=0.25)
3.0625
>>> misc.derivative(x3, 1, dx=1.0/2**16)
3.0000000002328306
```

Comment: Brilliant! I was blissfully unaware of that stipulation, I assumed that it's precision was more-or-less a set constant. Interesting then, I wonder what the performance difference is as accuracy is increased by shrinking the step size.

Comment: There won't be a huge performance difference from decreasing the step size because you're still doing the same number of arithmetic operations. What you have to watch out for is roundoff errors becoming problematic if the step size gets too small (for large floating point numbers, `(x+1) == x`). If you need accurate derivatives, you should consider [automatic differentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation).

Comment: Honestly ridiculous to even call that a derivative with such a large dx

Answer (score 1):

If you specify `dx` or the spacing to a small enough number you'll get a decent approximation.

```
>>> from scipy import misc
>>> def f(x): return x*x*x
... 
>>> misc.derivative(f,2,dx=0.1)
12.010000000000009

>>> round(misc.derivative(f,2,dx=0.1),0)
12.0
```